# Add information at the end of a file in c

Tags: c

I have to add website at the end of a website's tab which is composed of a csv file. The user may fill all the fields, if he puts 0 he goes to the next.
That's the 5 first lines :

```
Commune;Insee;url;Pop;https;Ser;Vserv;App;VApp;Langage;VLangag;Latitude;Longitude
Argentat;19010;argentat.fr;3042;non;SiteW;2;Inconnue;Inconnue;php;5.3.29;45.10;1.93
Canenx-et-Réaut;40064;mairie-info.com;175;non;SiteW;2;Inconnue;Inconnue;php;5.3.29;43.9;-0.4
Chaussan;69051;chaussan.fr;972;non;SiteW;2;Inconnue;Inconnue;Inconnue;Inconnue;45.637;4.6340
Étrez;1154;etrez.fr;803;non;SiteW;2;Inconnue;Inconnue;Inconnue;Inconnue;46.338;5.192
Gray ;70279;villegray.fr;6016;non;SiteW;2;Inconnue;Inconnue;php;5.2.10;47.4322;5.6109
```

Each field is divided by `;` as it's CSV.
My actual displaying program is the following :

```
while (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, curseur))
{
    char *token = strtok(buffer, ";");
    printf("Line %d\n", linenumber++);

    int column = 0;
    while (token != NULL)
    {
            printf("%2d    %s\n", column, token);

            switch (column)
            {
            case 0:                 
                strcpy((pSites + iSites)->Commune, token);
                break;
            case 1:
                strcpy((pSites + iSites)->url, token);
                break;
            case 2:
                strcpy((pSites + iSites)->https, token);
                break;
            case 3:
                strcpy((pSites + iSites)->Serveur, token);
                break;
            case 4:
                strcpy((pSites + iSites)->url, token);
                break;
            case 5:
                strcpy((pSites + iSites)->Application, token);
                break;
            case 6:
                strcpy((pSites + iSites)->VersionApplication, token);
                break;
            case 7:
                strcpy((pSites + iSites)->Langage, token);
                break;
            case 8:
                strcpy((pSites + iSites)->VersionLangage, token);
                break;
            }


                token = strtok(NULL, ";");
                column++;
            }

        iSites++;
    }
```

How can I add website at the end of the website's tab by using something like this :

```
while (strcmp((pLivre + i)->titre, "") != 0) {
        i++;
    }
    *(pLivre + i) = livreAjouter;
```

Comment: And the question is...?

Comment: Oups, just added the question

Comment: Your question is "too broad". Please read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and rephrase your question to get better replies.

Comment: What you want to do is unclear, can you give us an example of result? What about a [MCVE]?

Answer (score 0):

I'll ignore your text and answer your one liner heading.
You can write to the end of a file in C by

1. Opening it in append mode. See
   http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/cfileio.html
2. call fseek with a third argument of SEEK. See http://beej.us/guide/bgc/output/html/multipage/fseek.html